# mysql query select multiple rows where column value is same

Tags: php, mysql

i have this table

```
Column_1        Column_2
1                 value1
2                 value1
3                 value2
```

My php query is

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `Column_1` = 'value1' ";
print_r($query);
```

This returns only the 1st row. I am looking to display row 1 and 2. When I run the SQL in phpmyadmin it returns row 1 and 2. However, the php script only returns row 1... I also did an

```
echo count($query);
```

But it returns only 1. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: inside your table has how many "value1"?

Comment: Show us your complete code.

Comment: `value1` is in Column_2. And your where clause is on Column_1. Your query doesn't seem coherent with the sample data given.

Comment: Your source code does not do *anything* with the database. You have to actually send the query to the database and iterate over the result set.

Comment: 2 value1... sorry the ckause is in Column_2...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `Column_2` = 'value1' ";
$res = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($res)!=0) {
    while($rowData = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
        var_dump($rowData);
    }
}
```

- Use mysql_num_rows to count number of results.
- Use mysql_fetch_array or mysql_fetch_assoc to fetch data.

Comment: Thanks hoangvu68, your solution is detailed and perfect

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `Column_1` = 'value1' ";
$res = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc())
print_r($row);
```

You need add fetch in cycle.

Comment: Thanks Alexey, your answer hit the nail... except that you missed out $res in while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) and it's WHERE `Column_2` = 'value1' "; but thaks anyway...

Answer (score 0):

```
Use mysql_fetch_array() function
 $query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `Column_1` = 'value1' ";
 $res = mysql_query($query);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
   {
       echo $row['Column_1'];
       echo $row['value_1'];
   }
```